# How to convert a hash into a string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do an wolfram api using Ruby. I found that you can create a hash from text you put to find an answer on wolfram page. I managed to do something like this in my controller:

```
class CountController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @result = Wolfram.fetch('6*7')
    @hash = Wolfram::HashPresenter.new(@result).to_hash
    @pods = @hash[:pods]
  end
end
```

When I want to show this on my site I do something like this in my view:

```
<p>
    <b>Result:</b>
    <%= @result %>
    <br>
    <b>Hash:</b>
    <%= @hash %>
    <br>
    <b>Hash.pods</b>
    <%= @pods["Input"]%>
    <br>
</p>
```

And I have something like this on my page:

```
Result: #<Wolfram::Result:0x00000004758b78>
Hash: {:pods=>{"Input"=>["6×7"], "Result"=>["42"], "Number name"=>["forty-two"], "Number line"=>[""], "Illustration"=>["6 | \n | 7"]}, :assumptions=>{}}
Hash.pods ["6×7"]
```

I'd like to have just 6x7 instead of ["6x7"]. Is there a solution to change this hash into a string?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is being displayed like `[6x7]` is that your hash stores it within an array. Displaying it any other way will be misleading. However you can do it with:

```
Hash[@hash.map {|key, value| [key, (value.kind_of?(Array) && value.size == 1) ? value.first : value }]
```

Comment: Thx so much for answering but I'm bew in Ruby could you help me and tell me how to use the thing you wrote? Where should I put it in my code?